# Java variable type Collection for HashSet or other implementations?

Tags: java, collections, types, interface, declaration

I have often seen declarations like `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` or `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();` for fields in classes. For me it makes perfect sense to use the interfaces for the variable types to provide flexibility in the implementation. The examples above do still define which kind of `Collection`s have to be used, respectively which operations are allowed and how it should behave in some cases (due to docs).

Now consider the case where actually only the functionality of the `Collection` (or even the `Iterable`) interface is required to use the field in the class and the kind of `Collection` doesn't actually matter or I don't want to overspecify it. So I choose for example `HashSet` as implementation and declare the field as `Collection<String> collection = new HashSet<>();`.

Should the field then actually be of type `Set` in this case? Is this kind of declaration bad practice, if so, why? Or is it good practice to specify the actual type as less as possible (and still provide all required methods). The reason why I ask this is because I have hardly ever seen such a declaration and lately I get more an more in the situation where I only need to specify the functionality of the `Collection` interface.

Example:

```
// Only need Collection features, but decided to use a LinkedList
private final Collection<Listener> registeredListeners = new LinkedList<>();

public void init() {
    ExampleListener listener = new ExampleListener();
    registerListenerSomewhere(listener);
    registeredListeners.add(listener);
    listener = new ExampleListener();
    registerListenerSomewhere(listener);
    registeredListeners.add(listener);
}

public void reset() {
    for (Listener listener : registeredListeners) {
        unregisterListenerSomewhere(listener);
    }

    registeredListeners.clear();
}
```

Comment: Great question. A lot of it is a matter of taste and convention. I find List or Set cleaner and clearer in most cases, with the exception of method inputs, which should usually be as generic as possible.

Comment: The question was already answered in a broader sense, so as a *seemingly* overly specific question that is related to your particular example: What happens when somebody calls the `init()` method *twice*? Just think about how the choice of `Set` vs. `List` here interferes with the behavior of the `registerListenerSomewhere` method: Will it **there** be stored in a `Set` or in a `List`? If it's stored in a `List` there, but in a `Set` in your class, then calling `reset` will only remove *one* listener instance, but not all of them. It's difficult...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your example uses a *private field* it doesn't matter all that much about hiding the implementation type. You (or whoever is maintaining this class) can always just go look at the field's initializer to see what it is.

Depending on how it's used, though, it might be worth declaring a more specific interface for the field. Declaring it to be a `List` indicates that duplicates are allowed and that ordering is significant. Declaring it to be a `Set` indicates that duplicates aren't allowed and that ordering is not significant. You might even declare the field to have a particular implementation class if there's something about it that's significant. For example, declaring it to be `LinkedHashSet` indicates that duplicates aren't allowed but that ordering *is* significant.

The choice of whether to use an interface, and what interface to use, becomes much more significant if the type appears in the public API of the class, and on what the compatibility constraints on this class are. For example, suppose there were a method

```
public ??? getRegisteredListeners() {
    return ...
}
```

Now the choice of return type affects other classes. If you can change all the callers, maybe it's no big deal, you just have to edited other files. But suppose the caller is an application that you have no control over. Now the choice of interface is critical, as you can't change it without potentially breaking the applications. The rule here is usually to choose the most abstract interface that supports the operations you expect callers to want to perform.

Most of the Java SE APIs return `Collection`. This provides a fair degree of abstraction from the underlying implementation, but it also provides the caller a reasonable set of operations. The caller can iterate, get the size, do a contains check, or copy all the elements to another collection.

Some code bases use `Iterable` as the most-abstract interface to return. All it does is allow the caller to iterate. Sometimes this is all that's necessary, but it might be somewhat limiting compared to `Collection`.

Another alternative is to return a `Stream`. This is helpful if you think the caller might want to use stream's operations (such as filter, map, find, etc.) instead of iterating or using collection operations.

Note that if you choose to return `Collection` or `Iterable`, you need to make sure that you return an unmodifiable view or make a defensive copy. Otherwise, callers could modify your class's internal data, which would probably lead to bugs. (Yes, even an `Iterable` can permit modification! Consider getting an `Iterator` and then calling the `remove()` method.) If you return a `Stream`, you don't need to worry about that, since you can't use a `Stream` to modify the underlying source.

Note that I turned your question about the declaration of a field into a question about the declaration of method return types. There is this idea of "program to the interface" that's quite prevalent in Java. In my opinion it doesn't matter very much for local variables (which is why it's usually fine to use `var`), and it matters little for private fields, since those (almost) by definition affect only the class in which they're declared. However, the "program to the interface" principle is *very* important for API signatures, so those cases are where you really need to think about interface types. Private fields, not so much.

(One final note: there is a case where you need to be concerned about the types of private fields, and that's when you're using a reflective framework that manipulates private fields directly. In that case, you need to think of those fields as being public -- just like method return types -- even though they're not declared `public`.)

Comment: Excellent answer. The crux is `The rule here is usually to choose the most abstract interface that supports the operations you expect callers to want to perform.`

Answer (score 3):

As with all things, it's a question of tradeoffs. There are two opposing forces.

- The more generic the type, the more freedom the implementation has. If you use `Collection` you're free to use an `ArrayList`, `HashSet`, or `LinkedList` without affecting the user/caller.
- The more generic the return type, the less features there are available to the user/caller. A `List` provides index-based lookup. A `SortedSet` makes it easy to get contiguous subsets via `headSet`, `tailSet`, and `subSet`. A `NavigableSet` provides efficient O(log n) binary search lookup methods. If you return `Collection`, none of these are available. Only the most generic access functions can be used.

Furthermore, the sub-types guarantee special properties that `Collection` does not: `Set`s hold unique items. `SortedSet`s are sorted. `List`s have an order; they're not unordered bags of items. If you use `Collection` then the user/caller can't necessarily assume that these properties hold. They may be forced to code defensively and, for instance, handle duplicate items even if you know there won't be duplicates.

A reasonable decision process might be:

1. If O(1) indexed access is guaranteed, use `List`.
2. If elements are sorted and unique, use `SortedSet` or `NavigableSet`.
3. If element uniqueness is guaranteed and order is not, use `Set`.
4. Otherwise, use `Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do with the collection object.

```
Collection<String> cSet = new HashSet<>();
Collection<String> cList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here in this case if you want you can do :

```
cSet = cList;
```

But if you do like :

```
Set<String> cSet = new HashSet<>();
```

the above operation is not permissible though you can construct a new list using the constructor.

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

So basically depending on the usage you can use `Collection` or `Set` interface.